# binary 'operator' : no operator defined which takes a left-hand operand of type 'type' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

I have know idea why I get this error because I did implement the `operator ==` of `Fraction`. Even when I change `f==0` to `f==Fraction(1)`, it fails to compile.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

class Fraction
{
public:
    Fraction(int a, int b = 1) {}
    bool operator == (const Fraction&) { return true; }
};

template <typename T>
class Bar
{
public:
    bool test(const T& f) { return (f==0);} // ERROR
};

int main()
{
    Bar<Fraction> f;
    f.test(3);
}
```

Comment: `bool operator == (const Fraction&) const { return true; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the `operator==` member function of `Fraction` a `const` member function. Otherwise, it cannot be used with LHS which is `const` in this expression:

```
(f==0)
```